# Can you derive a formula for any internal energy of a gas as long as you know the degree of freedom?

Tags: gas-laws, energy

I have the following formula that I derived from studying my textbook that generalizes to all ideal gases:

Monoatomic molecular gases ($\ce{He, Ne}$ etc.)

*Degree of freedom*: **3**

$\ce \frac{3}{2}nRT = U$

Diatomic molecular gases ($\ce{O_2, N_2}$ etc.)

*Degree of freedom*: **5**

$\ce \frac{5}{2}nRT = U$

Polyatomic molecular gases ($\ce{CH_4, H_2O}$ etc.)

*Degree of freedom*: **6**

$\ce \frac{6}{2}nRT = U$

As you can see here, we observe that a general trend for the formula for the internal energy of a gas is:

$\frac{\text{degree of freedom}}{2}nRT$ = U

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is, look up "equipartition theorem".

Comment: It's correct for ideal gases.

Comment: cool! thank you orthocresol and chester miller